got issue when debug flutter app Execution failed for task ':rive_common:buildCMakeDebug[arm64-v8a]'
I got an issue when debugging my Flutter app:
these are my dependencies:
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.6
  awesome_dialog: ^3.2.1
  logger: ^2.2.0
  provider: ^6.1.2
  intl: ^0.19.0
  bluetooth_print: ^4.3.0
  flutter_svg: ^2.0.10+1
  dropdown_button2: ^2.3.9
  expansion_tile_card: ^3.0.0
  pinput: ^4.0.0
  shared_preferences: ^2.2.3
  jwt_decoder: ^2.0.1
  jumping_dot: ^0.0.6
  rive_common: ^0.4.7
  http: any

this is the error I got when running the flutter run:
PS C:\Users\HP\Downloads\test\flutter_application_1> flutter run          
Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone x86 in debug mode...
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':rive_common:buildCMakeDebug[arm64-v8a]'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: ninja: Entering directory `C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\rive_common-0.4.7\android\.cxx\Debug\p2o102m4\arm64-v8a'
  [1/1] Linking CXX shared library C:\Users\HP\Downloads\test\flutter_application_1\build\rive_common\intermediates\cxx\Debug\p2o102m4\obj\arm64-v8a\librive_text.so
  FAILED: C:/Users/HP/Downloads/test/flutter_application_1/build/rive_common/intermediates/cxx/Debug/p2o102m4/obj/arm64-v8a/librive_text.so
  cmd.exe /C "cd . && C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\25.1.8937393\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\clang++.exe --target=aarch64-none-linux-android21 --sysroot=C:/Users/HP/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk/25.1.8937393/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/sysroot -fPIC -g -DANDROID -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wformat -Werror=format-security   -DWITH_RIVE_TEXT -DWITH_RIVE_AUDIO_TOOLS -DWITH_RIVE_AUDIO -DMA_NO_RESOURCE_MANAGER -DHAVE_OT -DHB_NO_FALLBACK_SHAPE -DHB_NO_WIN1256 -DHB_NO_EXTERN_HELPERS -DHB_NO_CFF -DHB_NO_BUFFER_VERIFY -DHB_NO_BUFFER_MESSAGE -DHB_NO_PAINT -DHB_NO_MMAP -DHB_NO_META -DYOGA_EXPORT= -std=c++11 -fno-limit-debug-info  -static-libstdc++ -Wl,--build-id=sha1 -Wl,--no-rosegment -Wl,--fatal-warnings -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,--no-undefined -Qunused-arguments -shared -Wl,-soname,librive_text.so -o C:\Users\HP\Downloads\test\flutter_application_1\build\rive_common\intermediates\cxx\Debug\p2o102m4\obj\arm64-v8a\librive_text.so @CMakeFiles\rive_text.rsp  && cd ."
  ld: error: undefined hidden symbol: OT::cff2::accelerator_t::get_extents(hb_font_t*, unsigned int, hb_glyph_extents_t*) const
  >>> referenced by hb-subset-plan.cc:1019 (C:/Users/HP/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/rive_common-0.4.7/ios/harfbuzz/src/hb-subset-plan.cc:1019)
  >>>               CMakeFiles/rive_text.dir/C_/Users/HP/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/rive_common-0.4.7/ios/harfbuzz/src/hb-subset-plan.cc.o:(_update_instance_metrics_map_from_cff2(hb_subset_plan_t*))
  clang++: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
  ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.

  C++ build system [build] failed while executing:
      @echo off
      "C:\\Users\\HP\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\sdk\\cmake\\3.18.1\\bin\\ninja.exe" ^
        -C ^
        "C:\\Users\\HP\\AppData\\Local\\Pub\\Cache\\hosted\\pub.dev\\rive_common-0.4.7\\android\\.cxx\\Debug\\p2o102m4\\arm64-v8a" ^
        rive_text
    from C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\rive_common-0.4.7\android

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 46s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                             47.4s
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
PS C:\Users\HP\Downloads\test\flutter_application_1> 

I want solution to fix this error. i trid changing awesome dilog version and river version. but i got same error. i cleaned using flutter clean and tried manty times to solve this.

i don't have a clear explanation but rolling back on a previous version and afterward coming back on the last version.
Somehow fixed the bug

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Could you please elaborate what exactly you rolled back? I got the same problem
